# How can I detect whether user accessed a website using ipad or machine?

Tags: java, ipad, struts2, detection

I need to write two separate view section for users; one for those who access the website using iPad and those accessing otherwise.

I know it is possible in JavaScript, but I need to identify the device using Java.

I am using struts2 and hibernate in my project.

Comment: `request.getHeader("User-Agent")`

Comment: You are better off looking to CSS for this type of functionality.  E.G. see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6370690/418556).  The `User-Agent` string is not only notoriously unreliable, but once you've figured the typical string for an iPad, you realize that only covers ..40%(?) of your tablet users, who might otherwise be using an Android or Linux (or..) based tablet.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the "User-Agent" header the client sends.

Comment: When i detect user-agent and it get a long string like "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0 ", if it is mozilla and is crome another long message like "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" and if ipad another long message etc, from this how can i identify which is i am using to access the website?

Comment: That would be another question. Regular expressions come to mind.